# What is the source for "last in deed, first in thought"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat-songs

In the song Lecha Dodi the author states
סוף מעשה במחשבה תחלה - last in deed, [was] first in thought

I have seen this maxim attributed to Aristotle; is there a classic Jewish source for this in Tanacha, Chazal, Midrash etc?

Comment: http://jss.oxfordjournals.org/content/7/2/234.extract

Comment: Why can't the phrase in Lecha Dodi be translated as "the completion of an action begins with its initial thought"? In other words the term "sof" means "end".

Answer (score 4):

First things that come up on a search are

The words "רִאשׁוֹן לַמַּחֲשָׁבָה, אַחֲרוֹן לְמַעֲשֶׂה.".
[Zohar](http://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.237b.17/he/Zohar?with=all&lang=bi)

The words.   "תחילת המחשבה סוף המעשה"
[Kuzari 3.73](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/kuzari/kuzari3.htm), [Magid devorov liyakov](http://www.sefaria.org/Maggid_Devarav_leYaakov.126.2) said it is a maamar chazal (brings the midrash regarding shabbos)
The words "סוף מעשה תחילת המחשבה".
Also [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Maggid_Devarav_leYaakov.73.1/)

Ramban in the book believe and trust chapter 8

Comment: Note the Kuzari says he is quoting the Sages.